# Bot duplicates user messages when I use DirectLine channel

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I am using bot framework v4. I have developed a chatbot using `.Net Core`. The bot is integrated with `LUIS` and `Qna Maker`. One issue I am facing is that the bot duplicates the message that comes from the user. Please look at the screenshot below:

[image]

The replies I get from the bot are perfectly fine. The flow of the bot is as intended. I just cannot figure out why the message from user is being duplicated. I am using DirectLine for this. I will share whatever code part is needed.

```
{
  "activities": [
    {
      "type": "message",
      "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o|0000000",
      "timestamp": "2019-12-02T19:41:57.1284328Z",
      "channelId": "directline",
      "from": {
        "id": "CivicDevBot",
        "name": "CivicChat"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o"
      },
      "attachments": [
        {
          "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
          "content": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "version": "1.0",
            "body": [
              {
                "type": "Container",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                      {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "width": "auto",
                        "items": [
                          {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "size": "large",
                            "url": "https://i.imgur.com/ViaEUnA.png"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ],
                    "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                      {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "width": "auto",
                        "items": [
                          {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "size": "large",
                            "weight": "bolder",
                            "color": "light",
                            "text": "Welcome to CIVIC Financial Services",
                            "wrap": true
                          },
                          {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "size": "large",
                            "weight": "bolder",
                            "color": "light",
                            "text": "I am S.U.E",
                            "wrap": true
                          },
                          {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "color": "light",
                            "text": "I can help you answer your questions. Familiarize yourself with CIVIC Financial Services.",
                            "wrap": true
                          },
                          {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "color": "light",
                            "text": "If you want to talk to a Customer Service Agent, just type \"I want to talk to a Customer Service Agent\".",
                            "wrap": true
                          }
                        ],
                        "separator": true,
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Left"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "actions": [
              {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "data": {
                  "action": "aboutCivic"
                },
                "title": "About CIVIC"
              },
              {
                "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                "card": {
                  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                  "actions": [
                    {
                      "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                      "card": {
                        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                        "body": [
                          {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "We are open from Monday through Friday from 8:00am to 6:00pm.",
                            "wrap": true
                          }
                        ],
                        "style": "emphasis"
                      },
                      "title": "When are you open?"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                      "card": {
                        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                        "body": [
                          {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "size": "stretch",
                            "url": "https://i.imgur.com/gBVgI25.png",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "center"
                          },
                          {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "AZ, CA, CO, FL, GA, HI, NC, NV, OR, SC, TN, TX, UT, VA & WA",
                            "wrap": true
                          }
                        ],
                        "style": "emphasis"
                      },
                      "title": "Do you have an office near me? "
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                      "card": {
                        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                        "body": [
                          {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "8 to 10 days, it all depends on how it takes to get access to the property.",
                            "wrap": true
                          }
                        ],
                        "style": "emphasis"
                      },
                      "title": "How quickly can we close? "
                    }
                  ],
                  "style": "emphasis"
                },
                "title": "FAQs"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "entities": [],
      "replyToId": "8WGOnspSxN3"
    },
    {
      "type": "message",
      "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o|0000001",
      "timestamp": "2019-12-02T19:43:39.96502Z",
      "serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/",
      "channelId": "directline",
      "from": {
        "id": "r_1575315715",
        "name": "",
        "role": "user"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o"
      },
      "textFormat": "plain",
      "locale": "en-GB",
      "text": "teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
      "entities": [
        {
          "type": "ClientCapabilities",
          "requiresBotState": true,
          "supportsListening": true,
          "supportsTts": true
        }
      ],
      "channelData": {
        "siteDomain": "https://websiteae1.stackblitz.io/"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "message",
      "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o|0000002",
      "timestamp": "2019-12-02T19:43:41.7278914Z",
      "channelId": "directline",
      "from": {
        "id": "CivicDevBot",
        "name": "CivicChat"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o"
      },
      "text": "Sorry, I didn't understand. Consider rephrasing your question or contacting a customer agent",
      "attachments": [],
      "entities": [],
      "replyToId": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o|0000001"
    },
    {
      "type": "message",
      "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o|0000003",
      "timestamp": "2019-12-02T20:00:25.784598Z",
      "serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/",
      "channelId": "directline",
      "from": {
        "id": "r_1575315715",
        "name": "",
        "role": "user"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o"
      },
      "textFormat": "plain",
      "locale": "en-GB",
      "text": "helo",
      "channelData": {
        "siteDomain": "https://websiteae1.stackblitz.io/"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "message",
      "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o|0000004",
      "timestamp": "2019-12-02T20:00:26.5739342Z",
      "channelId": "directline",
      "from": {
        "id": "CivicDevBot",
        "name": "CivicChat"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o"
      },
      "text": "Sorry, I didn't understand. Consider rephrasing your question or contacting a customer agent",
      "attachments": [],
      "entities": [],
      "replyToId": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o|0000003"
    },
    {
      "type": "message",
      "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o|0000005",
      "timestamp": "2019-12-02T20:00:27.3293896Z",
      "serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/",
      "channelId": "directline",
      "from": {
        "id": "r_1575315715",
        "name": "",
        "role": "user"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o"
      },
      "textFormat": "plain",
      "locale": "en-GB",
      "text": "hello",
      "channelData": {
        "siteDomain": "https://websiteae1.stackblitz.io/"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "message",
      "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o|0000006",
      "timestamp": "2019-12-02T20:00:27.6064185Z",
      "channelId": "directline",
      "from": {
        "id": "CivicDevBot",
        "name": "CivicChat"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "id": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o"
      },
      "text": "Hello",
      "inputHint": "acceptingInput",
      "attachments": [],
      "entities": [],
      "replyToId": "BR1wBZw7w2852JMLobk0EC-o|0000005"
    }
  ],
  "watermark": "6"
}
```

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. You're saying you only type "lolo" once, but it shows up in the conversation history twice? Is this happening for every message? This sounds like it could be related to this: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5674 . Please try calling [Get Activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#get-activities) so you can see if the user's question actually exists as a duplicated activity.

Comment: yes your understanding is correct.

Comment: What is the result of the Get Activities API?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Hey @KyleDelaney I was on a vacation. i am looking into it now. I will get back to you with an update

Comment: @KyleDelaney I have added the response of Get Activities. I do not see messages from user being duplicated. 
I went over the github URL you shared, I am not using token to exchange the Direct Line secret like OP.

Comment: The activities I see in that transcript are from today, so they don't match the screenshot. But I'm guessing you're saying every activity from the user shows up twice in the chat window. This indicates that the problem is with your Direct Line client, so you'll need to provide the relevant client code. Does it always say "Send failed. Retry." under the first message in each pair?

Comment: they transcript is from today but the same thing happens every time. Yes, it does say "Send failed. Retry" and then duplicate appears which is received and processed by the bot

Comment: This isn't a problem with Direct Line or the bot. Again, you'll need to provide the relevant client code if you want to get help with this.

Comment: what part of client code do you need?

Comment: The part that processes user input and sends it to the bot. Now that I think about it, it looks like you're using Web Chat. Are you using Web Chat?

Comment: I am using both webchat and direct line for the same bot. There are 2 different scenarios that I am catering but this is only happening with the DirectLine channel. i will update my question with the code

Comment: Please understand that Web Chat is a Direct Line client. They are not separate channels. Are you saying you are connecting your bot to multiple Direct Line clients, with one being Web Chat and one being your own client? Which one is the one pictured in your screenshot?

Comment: Let me clarify. I am using DirectLine webchat and Iframe webchat. This is happening in DirectLine only!

Comment: You still need to provide your client code

Comment: @hkhan Is this issue already got resolved ?if yes pls give details here